# Adding Excel Addin folder to Trusted locations with Inno Setup

Tags: excel, inno-setup, pascalscript, vba

I'm using the Inno Setup [ExcelAddinInstaller](https://github.com/bovender/ExcelAddinInstaller) which works great.

```pascal
{
  Looks up the localized Addins folder in the registry.
  This function is used in the [Files] section of the
  script, where function calls always expect a parametrized
  function. This function does not require a parameter.
  Therefore, a dummy parameter is defined.
}
function GetDestDir(dummyparameter: string): string;
var
  Addins: string;
  s: string;
  CallName: string;
  i: integer;
begin
  if DestDir = '' then
  begin
    CallName := 'GetDestDir(' + dummyparameter + '): ';
    log(CallName+'Trying to find addins folder name');

    {
      Note the trailing backslash
    }
    DestDir := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\Microsoft\');

    {
      Loop through possible version numbers of Excel and find out if
      any installed version uses an addin folder other than "addins".
      This can be the case with international versions (other than English).
      If an addin folder name that is different from "Addins" is found,
      the addin will be installed into a dedicated folder.
    }
    for i := 8 to 32 do
    begin
      s := '';
      if RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Software\Microsoft\Office\'
        +IntToStr(i)+'.0\Common\General', 'AddIns', s) then
      begin
        if Length(Addins) > 0 then
        begin
          {
            If the Addins variable has been set already and we encounter
            a different name, reset everything in order to use a dedicated
            name further on.
          }
          if s <> Addins then
          begin
            {
              Set the Addins variable to a zero-length string to force
              using a dedicated dir name later.
            }
            log(CallName+'Found alternative Addins key for version '+IntToStr(i)+': "'+s+'"');
            Addins := '';
            {
              Once a single dir name that is different from "Addins" was
              found, we can exit the loop.
            }
            break;
          end 
        end
        else
        begin
          {
            Addins variable has zero length: Set it to the current value of s
          }
          log(CallName+'Found first Addins key: version '+IntToStr(i)+', "'+s+'"');
          Addins := s;
        end
      end
    end;

    {
      Check if the Addins variable contains something now; if not, use
      a default value ('XL Toolbox')
    }
    if Addins = '' then
    begin
      DestDir := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\Microsoft\Addins\');
      RegisterWithFullPath := true;
      log(CallName+'Using dedicated folder: "'+DestDir+'"');  
    end
    else
    begin
      DestDir := ExpandConstant('{userappdata}\Microsoft\' + Addins);
      RegisterWithFullPath := false;
      log(CallName+'Installing to default Addins folder: ' + DestDir);  
    end;
  end;
  result := DestDir; 
end;
```

But it happens that in Excel 2016 and 2013 the folder where the add-in is installed by default is not defined as a "trusted location" by Excel, making the add-in to install but not to be displayed in Excel.

I'm looking for adding the path returned by the `GetDestDir` be added to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Secur‌​‌​ity\Trusted Locations\MyLocation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code finds the first unused `LocationX` subkey under `Trusted Locations` and writes the `Addins` path there:

```pascal
const
  TrustedLocationsKey =
    'Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations';

procedure AddAddinsToExcelTrustedLocations;
var
  LocationIndex: Integer;
  LocationKey: string;
  Path: string;
begin
  if not RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, TrustedLocationsKey) then
  begin
    MsgBox('Excel trusted locations registry key not found', mbError, MB_OK);
  end
    else
  begin
    { Find unused LocationX }
    LocationIndex := 0;
    repeat
      LocationKey := Format('%s\Location%d', [TrustedLocationsKey, LocationIndex]);
      Log(Format('Trying %s', [LocationKey]));
      Inc(LocationIndex);
    until (not RegKeyExists(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, LocationKey));

    Log(Format('Will use %s', [LocationKey]));

    { Addins is the variable from your question code }
    Path := GetDestDir('');
    if not RegWriteStringValue(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, LocationKey, 'Path', Path) then
    begin
      MsgBox(
        Format('Cannot add %s to Excel trusted locations', [Path]), mbError, MB_OK);
    end
      else
    begin
      Log(Format('Added %s to Excel trusted locations', [Path]));
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    AddAddinsToExcelTrustedLocations;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The addin indeed installs properly in "Templates" but it doesn't register in Excel. Could you help with the Pascal function that should do the task?

Comment: Your question does not show the code for registration. Are you even sure it's the right approach to install the AddIn to the Templates?

Comment: I'm not sure that it is the best approach but I need to install it in a "Trusted location" otherwise it will not show in Excel tabs. The code appears [here](http://metrics-institute.com/avibenita/InnoRegister.txt)

Comment: So you should probably start with an Excel-only question on *"How to install AddIn to a trusted location"* (possibly on [su], as that' not a programming question). And once you get an answer, come here to ask how to implement that in Inno Setup.

Comment: Ok, I have to add "Addins" folder to the trusted locations in the registry

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Security\Trusted Locations\_MyLocation_ where the value should be 
C:\Users\_Username_\AppData\Raming\Microsoft\**Addins**\

Is it possible to do it through Innosetup?

Comment: Though in my installation of Excel 2016, I already have `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Templates` in the `Trusted Locations`. So why do you think that adding `Addins` would make a difference, when it does not for `Templates`?

Comment: When I change the addin destination directory to TEMPLATES (in the installer code)  in the code, the addin appears there but for some reasons, it doesn't activate and appear in Excel as it does it properly when installed in the ADDINS folder. So that the solution will be either to make the code working for the TEMPLATES  option or making the  ADDINS folder as a trusted location

Comment: Well, you didn't answer my question. Anyway, edit your question with your findings and I can then post a solution. Though I'm not convinced it helps you.

Comment: The code should create MyLocation key in the registry as follows:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Secur‌​ity\Trusted Locations/MyLocation where the value should be 

C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft/Addins/
Is it possible to do it through Innosetup?